# Можно изучать Microsoft SQL Server без опыта работы с БД?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Я учусь программировать на C# и хочу параллельно изучать БД. Для себя я выбрал СУБД Microsoft SQL Serve. Понятия БД и СУБД я различаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли изучать microsoft sql server без опыта работы с БД?

Можно. Любой, кто изучает, как работать с чем-либо впервые, по определению не имеет опыта работы с предметом изучения. Только просто *изучать* смысла нет, надо что-то *делать* и как-то *использовать* так, чтобы был практический результат, помимо приобретения абстрактных знаний.